# Add more button in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I am trying to add rows in my django template using JavaScript but it is not working like it's supposed to:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>gffdfdf</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.formset.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <form id="myForm" action="" method="post" class="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2> Team</h2>
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} : {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ form.player.management_form }}

        <h3> Product Instance(s)</h3>
        <table id="table-product" class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>player name</th>
                <th>highest score</th>
                <th>age</th>
            </tr>

            </thead>
            {% for player in form.player %}
                <tbody class="player-instances">

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ player.pname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ player.hscore }}</td>
                    <td>{{ player.age }}</td>
                    <td> <input id="input_add" type="button" name="add" value=" Add More " class="tr_clone_add btn data_input"> </td>

                </tr>

                </tbody>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>

    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var i = 1;
    $("#input_add").click(function() {
        $("tbody tr:first").clone().find(".data_input").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('class')== 'tr_clone_add btn data_input'){
                $(this).attr({
                    'id': function(_, id) { return "remove_button" },
                    'name': function(_, name) { return "name_remove" +i },
                    'value': 'Remove'
                }).on("click", function(){
                    var a = $(this).parent();
                    var b= a.parent();
                    i=i-1
                    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(i);
                    b.remove();

                    $('.player-instances tr').each(function(index, value){
                        $(this).find('.data_input').each(function(){
                            $(this).attr({
                                'id': function (_, id) {
                                    var idData= id;
                                    var splitV= String(idData).split('-');
                                    var fData= splitV[0];
                                    var tData= splitV[2];
                                    return fData+ "-" +index + "-" + tData
                                },
                                'name': function (_, name) {
                                    var nameData= name;
                                    var splitV= String(nameData).split('-');
                                    var fData= splitV[0];
                                    var tData= splitV[2];
                                    return fData+ "-" +index + "-" + tData
                                }
                            });
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
            else{
                $(this).attr({
                    'id': function (_, id) {
                        var idData= id;
                        var splitV= String(idData).split('-');
                        var fData= splitV[0];
                        var tData= splitV[2];
                        return fData+ "-" +i + "-" + tData
                    },
                    'name': function (_, name) {
                        var nameData= name;
                        var splitV= String(nameData).split('-');
                        var fData= splitV[0];
                        var tData= splitV[2];
                        return fData+ "-" +i + "-" + tData
                    }
                });

            }
        }).end().appendTo("tbody");
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(1+i);
        i++;

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the above code creates a form with three fields i.e `player name`, `highest score` and `age` with a `add more` button

but according to [this](https://ruddra.com/posts/working-with-formset/) it should create the following :

```
<!-- First row of the table -->

<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="form-0-name" id="id_form-0-name" /></td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="form-0-quantity" id="id_form-0-quantity" />
  </td>
  <td><input type="number" name="form-0-price" id="id_form-0-price" /></td>
  <td>
    <input
      id="input_add"
      type="button"
      name="add"
      value=" Add More "
      class="tr_clone_add btn data_input"
    />
  </td>
</tr>

<!-- Second row of the table -->

<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="form-1-name" id="id_form-1-name" /></td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="form-1-quantity" id="id_form-1-quantity" />
  </td>
  <td><input type="number" name="form-1-price" id="id_form-1-price" /></td>
  <td>
    <input
      id="remove_button"
      type="button"
      name="remove_button1"
      value=" Remove "
      class="tr_clone_add btn data_input"
    />
  </td>
</tr>

<!-- more inline formset are going to rendered here -->
```

But when I create another row in the form it creates another row with same `name` and `id`.

See:

```
<tbody class="player-instances">

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="form-0-pname" id="id_form-0-pname"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="form-0-hscore" id="id_form-0-hscore"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="form-0-age" id="id_form-0-age"></td>
                    <td> <input id="input_add-0-undefined" type="button" name="add-0-undefined" value=" Add More " class="tr_clone_add btn data_input"> </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="form-0-pname" id="id_form-0-pname"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="form-0-hscore" id="id_form-0-hscore"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="form-0-age" id="id_form-0-age"></td>
                    <td> <input id="remove_button-1-undefined" type="button" name="name_remove1-1-undefined" value="Remove" class="tr_clone_add btn data_input"> </td>

                </tr></tbody>
```

Why does it not add the row with updated `name` and `id` ?

Update:

Models.py

```
class Player(models.Model):
    pname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hscore = models.IntegerField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
       return self.pname

class Team(models.Model):
    tname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    player= models.ManyToManyField(Player)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tname
```

Views.py

```
def post(request):
   if request.POST:
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        print("form", form)
        form.player_instances = PlayerFormset(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            team= Team()
            team.tname= form.cleaned_data['tname']
            team.save()

        if form.player_instances.cleaned_data is not None:
            for item in form.player_instances.cleaned_data:
                player = Player()
                player.pname= item['pname']
                player.hscore= item['hscore']
                player.age= item['age']
                player.save()
                team.player.add(player)
            team.save()

   else:
        form = TeamForm()
        return render(request, 'packsapp/employee/new.html', {'form':form})
```

Forms.py

```
class PlayerForm(forms.Form):
    pname = forms.CharField()
    hscore= forms.IntegerField()
    age = forms.IntegerField()

PlayerFormset= formset_factory(PlayerForm)

class TeamForm(forms.Form):
   tname= forms.CharField()
   player= PlayerFormset()
```

Comment: Hi, you're not loading the js script correctly. You need to put `<script src="{% static '/static/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>` rather than `<script src="/static/jquery.formset.js"></script>` (you need to load the static file). Also you need to put the tag {% load static %} in the beginning of your html.

Comment: @vcruvinelr I have added the `{% load static %} ` but still no change.. actually there is no  `jquery.formset.js` file in mt static/js folder.

Comment: You're loading the `formset` through `js` or `from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory`?. I need a full view from your app to help you. If possible, show all the steps (models, forms, views, templates) in order. With this I can try to help and solve the problem.

Comment: @vcruvinelr I have updated the question with views, models and forms.py.. the template is already mentioned above

Comment: @vcruvinelr and yes i am loading the formset through `from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory`